# How can i save facebook user login session in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-login

I want to save users facebook login sessions in my app, so the user doesn't have to sign in every time the app reopened. I already did this with google but can not find anything about Facebook.
  Here is my authentication code.

```dart
  Future<void> logInWithFacebook() async {
    final result = await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);

    switch (result.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        final token = result.accessToken.token;
        final graphResponse = await http.get(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,picture,email&access_token=${token}');
        final profile = JSON.jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);
        print(profile);
        await Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePage()));
        setState(() {
          userProfile = profile;
          isAuth = true;
        });
        break;

      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        setState(() => isAuth = false);
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        setState(() => isAuth = false);
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should use state [management](https://medium.com/flutter-community/let-me-help-you-to-understand-and-choose-a-state-management-solution-for-your-app-9ffeac834ee3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your token or your login state inside Shared Preference. Here is the link to the Flutter Package

[Shared Preference Package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

I would suggest making this a global variable, to share its access with the whole application package.
After that, you can do something like this

```
prefs.setBool("pref_logged_user",isLoggedIn);
```

Where pref_logged_user is the key which will be used to access the data

```
bool isLoggedIn = await prefs.getBool("pref_logged_user")??false;
```

?? is used to check whether the output is null. If null then return false;

Comment: Thanks, i was searching for this all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Use user sessions  instead. Check out [Consession](https://api.pub.dev/packages/consession). The package adds user session support in Flutter and is easy to use.

```
// Store value to session
await Consession().set("isAuth", isAuth);

// Retrieve item from session
dynamic token = await Consession().get("isAuth");
```